# How to get DataTimeZone with UTC-05:00

Tags: php

It might be a simple question since I am kind of novice on PHP, I need to create `DateTimeZone` on `UTC-05:00`, I have taken a look around, most of example uses the name of city to get timezone like:

```
$dateTimeZoneJapan = new DateTimeZone("Asia/Tokyo");
```

But I actually don't know what kind of city on `UTC-05:00` (it's dynamic, maybe `UTC+05:00` or other values), I see:

```
$utcTimeZone = new DateTimeZone("UTC");
```

is working but:

```
$myTimeZone = new DateTimeZone("UTC-05:00");
```

isn't working.

So, how do I create `DateTimeZone` on `UTC-05:00`? The [constructor](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetimezone.construct.php) of `DateTimeZone` does not mention on this

Comment: Since this is not possible (see my answer below), why are you trying to do this? Maybe there's another solution for the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: @deceze: thanks for the answer, I would like to create a `DataTime` based on the timezone `UTC:-05:00` for example

Comment: Again, that's **not possible.** What do you want to do with this timezone?

Comment: @deceze: I just want to create `new DateTime()` with this timezone

Comment: @deceze: seem I found out another way: `new DateTime('2013-10-30 03:00:00-05:00')`, it works well for me

Comment: Also see my amended answer.

Comment: Note that the "timezone" `-05:00` does not really work if you want to do date/time calculations. If you add half a year to the timestamp, it may be off by an hour compared to the actual time in the timezone you're targeting. So, if you're not going to "do" anything much with this "timezone", that's ok. Otherwise, you may be in trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's exactly the problem. You cannot go from offset to timezone. There are many timezones which have the same offset at any given time, but these are different timezones because their offset changes at different times of the year. A timezone is not the same as an offset; a timezone is a *set of rules* during which times of the year which offset is active. The best you could do is make a list of timezones whose current offset is -05:00, but you cannot identify one particular timezone.

---

Having said that, PHP does support compatibility timezones `Etc/GMT+1` etc. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.others.php. But note that these may not be the exact same timezones as UTC+XX and:

> ## Warning
>
> Please do not use any of the timezones listed here (besides UTC), they only exist for backward compatible reasons.